# why does the textbox always returning null when there is a commas in numbers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller, view and model like below

```
//model
public class ItemViewModel
{
   public string name {get;set;}
   public decimal? TotalPrice { get; set; }
}

//controller
[HttpPost]
[MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Submit")]
public ActionResult Submit(ItemViewModel model)
{
   decimal? a = model.TotalPrice;
   Console.WriteLine(a);
}

//view
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
<input type="submit" name="action:Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit"/>
```

when I debug the model.TotalPrice is always null when there is a commas in number for example 10,234,776, but if there is no comma it gets the actual result. any idea?

Comment: What is the code of model ?  Are there any validation attribute on the property ?

Comment: Somewhere you will need to specify that the parsing for the values should allow for thousands separators.

Comment: What if you use points (e.g) 10.234

Comment: Do share the ItemViewModel as I am guessing there might be issues with data binding.

Comment: I just edited the code  I have added a view model to the code above @ManojChoudhari

Comment: I just edited the code I have added a view model to the code above  @Tayyab

Comment: Looks like the default model binder may be having troubles converting your Total Price input to a decimal in the first place. One solution can be to change your TotalPrice to string type and then write your logic to convert the string to decimal(with comma or without comma).

Comment: The value of a text box is a string. If you bind it to a Decimal you are implicitly asking for a conversion. When that conversion fails you may not see the error message. Instead the view model should provide a string, and you should handle the conversion yourself.

Comment: if I change it to a string, I get a lot of errors in my code, is there another way? @Tayyab

Comment: You may find [this article](https://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/) very helpful to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Change your ItemViewModel like
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
//Introduce your custom Parser to handle the comma case
private  bool MyTryParse(string toParse, out decimal result)
{
    //Remove commas
    string formatted = toParse.Replace(",", "");

    return decimal.TryParse(formatted, out result);
}

//And your controller be like
[HttpPost]
[MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Submit")]
public ActionResult Submit(ItemViewModel model)
{
    decimal a = null;

    if (MyTryParse(model.TotalPrice, out a))
    {
        //Success code
    }
    else
    {
        //some error code
    }

    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Note: Not maybe the best but a workable solution. Hope this helps your case.

Comment: @chaeusang chen

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs a decimal, the text box needs a string. The ViewModel is where you do the conversion.

```
private decimal totalPriceDecimal;
private string totalPriceString;

    public string TotalPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.totalPriceString();
        }

        set
        {
            this.totalPriceString = value;

            decimal temp;
            if (int.TryParse(value, out temp))
            {
                this.totalPriceDecimal = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then your code that needs a decimal can use totalPriceDecimal, while you can bind the string to the text box.

More importantly, if the user enters something that can't be parsed, you know and can display an error message.

Answer (score 0):

i tried it and it is working fine 
the following is the code and the view assigned

```
[HttpPost]

public ActionResult Submit(ItemViewModel model)
 {
   decimal? a = model.TotalPrice;
   Console.WriteLine(a);
   return View();
 }

public ActionResult Submit()
  {
    return View();
  }
```

//=====================View============================

@model WebApplication4.Controllers.ItemViewModel

@Html.BeginForm()
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TotalPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    
}

Comment: The issue was with 10,234,776 (comma separated value) passed as input.